# jquery append element into dynamic list

Tags: jquery, mysql, dynamic, append

in my page I have:

- **a DB-loaded list of appointments**  ordered by datetime DESC.
- **a search bar** to refine my list of elements (through GET requests)
- **a form** to add a new element to DB

I want to be able to add a new appointment "Y" (with Jquery) and append it in the list without losing the datetime order.

If the list was **static** I could query DB for the first appointment wich datetime comes right before "appointment Y" get its ID (Ex."2") and place with jquery my new "appointment Y" right after the element with  ID=2.

But with a **dynamic** list that wouldn't work,cause element ID=2 might not be there and jquery wouldnt know where to place my "appointment Y"..
I would need to query DB only between those elements that appear in the list..I think.

**Should i send over through jquery, with the appointment data, also the GET variables i used for the search?And how i get them?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of templates (tmpl) and $.ajax.  After the new appointment has been added to the database you can call a JavaScript function to invoke an $.ajax call.  In the callback function you can then inject the newly updated json data into a template.  This type of workflow will allow you to update lists without a page refresh.

Here's more information on getting started with jQuery templates...
http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html